# How do I take several Python lists of numbers and find the latest occurrence of a specific element?

Tags: python

I have four time series of the same length.  When one element is missing, it has a value of 0.

What is the idiomatic way to find the index of the latest occurrence of 0 in any of the lists?

Comment: what should this do when no 0 is found? return None or raise exception?

Answer (score 1):

If `timeseries` is a list containing the four timeseries, you could reverse each timeseries, use `zip` to group together 4-tuple time-slices, and `enumerate` to record the index.

```
# timeseries=[range(1,5),range(1,5),range(1,5),range(1,5)]    
for idx,data in enumerate(zip(*[ts[::-1] for ts in timeseries])):
    if not all(data):
        break
else:
    idx=None
idx=len(timeseries[0])-idx-1
# print(idx)
```

When the for-loop breaks, `idx` will hold the value of the index with a timeseries-value of zero. If no value is zero, then `idx` set to equal `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def rindex(l,v):
    for i,el in enumerate(reversed(l)):
        if el == v:
            return len(l) - i - 1
    return -1
series = [[1,2], [0, 0, 1], ...]
max(rindex(l, 0) for l in series)
```

Comment: I think will be slow because `reversed` will build an entire reversed version of the list for each call to `rindex`.

Comment: @Walter Mundt reversed returns an iterator and takes virtually no memory. Just confirmed that by building a 100MB array and reversing it twice - not a single MB more required. Also, note that type(reversed([])) == <type 'listreverseiterator'>.

Comment: @Walter, phihag: in general this depends on the version of Python; more recent versions have been changing builtin functions to return iterables instead of lists.

Comment: @katrielalex What exactly is more recent? I reproduced it with Python 2.4.

Comment: my bad, `reversed` does indeed return an iterator in all versions of Python for which it is defined. I was thinking of `map`. Sorry!

Comment: @phihag, indeed, `type(reversed([])) == <type 'listreverseiterator'>`. But `listreverseiterator` doesn't appear to have a `find` method... I got `AttributeError: 'listreverseiterator' object has no attribute 'find'` when I ran this code.

Comment: @senderle Oops, you're totally right. Updated with a manual search.

Comment: +1 then, except that I think the indices will be off by one -- if `len(l) == 5` and `i == 0`, for example, then `5 - 0` will be 5, not 4. Sorry to be a pest.

Comment: @senderle Not a pest - it was my fault after all. Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A functional approach (returns None if 0 is not found anywhere):

```
timeseries = [
  [1, 2, 3, 5],
  [4, 3, 0, 2],
  [4, 2, 0, 1],
  [4, 2, 6, 0],
]

etimeseries = list(enumerate(zip(*timeseries)))
index = next((idx for (idx, xs) in reversed(etimeseries) if not all(xs)), None)
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timeseries = [   [1, 2, 3, 5],   [4, 3, 0, 2],   [4, 2, 0, 1],   [4, 2, 6, 0] ] 
print "timeseries==",timeseries

res = [ (i for i in xrange(len(li)-1,-1,-1) if li[i]==0).next() if 0 in li else None
        for li in timeseries ]

print
print 'res==',res
```

result

```
timeseries== [[1, 2, 3, 5], [4, 3, 0, 2], [4, 2, 0, 1], [4, 2, 6, 0]]

res== [None, 2, 2, 3]
```